# Git push cannot write to object file - permission denied

Tags: permissions, git

I'm on a cloned repo and trying to push to my remote branch.
Committing works just fine, however whenever I try to push I get this:

```
error: unable to write file ./objects/foo/bar: Permission denied
```

I own all files in the local repository and usually pushing works just fine, however after some time this error occurs and I cannot push.

The only thing resolving the issue, is to revert to the last commit on origin and try to find the file which is supposed to be causing trouble.

I then touch a new file and paste the contents from the old "broken" file.
Sometimes this doesn't help either and obviously this is not a manageable workaround.

Comment: if you commit/push from different PCs/users, you could create objects whose permissions are not appropriate. I had this problem in the past.
Check this, if it can help:
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/05/git-push-error/

Comment: Huge tip @2Fl0w3rs!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and found this question.
I read the tip posted at https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/05/git-push-error/ and will summarize what fixed the problem (for me).

The fix was to configure the host holding the GIT REPO so that it contained a shared group into which all git users were added.  For example, /etc/group

```
git:x:4001:user1,user2
```

Next, on the host holding the git repo, run the following commands:

```
cd /local/git-repos/repo1.git
sudo chgrp -R git objects
sudo chmod -R g+rws objects
```

For me this fixed the problem.   The referenced article explains more about configuring a repo as a shared repo but I haven't (yet) done this.

```
git config core.sharedRepository group
```

Why can this happen?  Read on if you are interested.

#### Why does this happen

For me this happened when I setup a private git repo that I (user1) was sharing with some co-workers.  The repo was on my host (say host1) and user2@host2 was using it as well.

Below are the steps I used to set this up, and in the appropriate place I explain where the problem occurs.

1. I am user1@host1, and I create a bare git repo using:

   ```
   mkdir /local/git-repos
   cd /local/git-repos
   git init --bare repo1.git
   ```
2. I setup a ~/.ssh/config file so that the name used for the git repo is a logical name.  This is done so that if I move my box to another machine, all I have to do is update my host alias to the new computer name.

   File: `$HOME/.ssh/config`

   ```
   Host mygithost
       HostName host1
   ```
3. I then clone the repo using

   ```
   cd $HOME
   git clone mygithost:/local/git-repos/repo1.git
   cd repo1
   # Add files and use normal git commands
   git add -u .
   git commit
   git push
   ```

   The updates are sent to the git repo on computer
4. Setup user2 so they can access this same GIT repo

   - You'll need to setup the $HOME/.ssh/config file as done for user1.
   - Make sure the user an ssh into host1 as themselves.

   ```
   ssh user2@mygithost echo it worked
   cd $HOME
   git clone mygithost:/local/git-repos/repo1.git
   ```

   **At this point both users, user1 and user2 are able to access the shared GIT repo.**

   If **BOTH** users make commits then the git REPO object files will have some files owned by `user1` and some files owned by `user2`.  The problem is that later when `user1` tries to push files to the GIT HOST the `object` files and directories created might be owned by `user2` so the following error occurs.

   ```
   error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
   fatal: failed to write object
   error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
    ! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
   error: failed to push some refs to john@192.168.100.1:/home/git/myproj
   ```

   **The solution is to configure the git bare repo so that any user can read/write files created by any other user.**  This is done by the next step using `UNIX GROUP` permissions.
5. Setup the REPO so that different users can access the git repo.

   - Create a GROUP that all users can be part of

     ```
     sudo vi /etc/group
     git:x:4001:user1,user2
     ```
   - Change all of the files so that they are properly in the newly created group.

     ```
     cd /local/git-repos/repo1.git
     sudo chgrp -R git objects
     sudo chmod -R g+rws objects
     ```

   *Use whatever shared group you created above (`git` in this example).*

NOTE: The group-suid bit is important as it causes future files/directories that are created to retain the same settings as the parent directory.
From https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/suid-sgid-sticky-bit, it says:

> If set on a directory, any files created in the directory will have their group ownership set to that of the directory owner

#### Summary

This error should not typically happen on any normally hosted GIT REPO.  But it can happen in the situation described where a private (file based) repo is setup and shared by multiple users.